# React Native elements: List not scrolling

Tags: react-native

Repo link is [here](https://github.com/practicia1234/Practicia/tree/devSam)

I am unable to scroll the listview. I tried the following solution but am getting errors:

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

...

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>
    <List>
      ...
    </List>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Code for that page is here, the error using scrollview occurs whether I am using the element from react-native or react-native-elements.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Scrollview } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'December 8, 2017'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'December 8, 1973'
  },

class Individuals extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }} >

      <List containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
        {
          list.map((l, i) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              avatar={{ uri: l.avatar_url }}
              key={i}
              title={l.name}
              subtitle={`Last Practiced: ${l.subtitle}`}
            />
          ))
        }
      </List>

     </View>


   );
  }
}

export default Individuals;
```

Answer (score 1):

**you most likely misspelled the ScrollView in import statement**

just change it from

```
import { Text, View, Scrollview } from 'react-native'
```

to

```
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
```

and

this is how it works for me

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
const list = [
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Chris Jackson",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 1973"
},
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Chris Jackson",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 1973"
},
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Chris Jackson",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 1973"
},
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Chris Jackson",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 1973"
},
{
name: "Amy Farha",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 2017"
},
{
name: "Chris Jackson",
avatar_url:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg",
subtitle: "December 8, 1973"
}
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1 }}>
    {list.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        avatar={{ uri: l.avatar_url }}
        key={i}
        title={l.name}
        subtitle={`Last Practiced: ${l.subtitle}`}
      />
    ))}
  </ScrollView>
);
}
}
```